# Pass unquoted parameter as character in select function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(
    name = c("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo", "Stuart", "Pete"),
    instrument1 = c("guitar", "bass", "guitar", "drums", "bass","drums"),
    instrument2 = c("guitar", "bass", "guitar", "drums", "bass","drums"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

And I create a function like this:

```
sel <- function(df, variable) {
    var <- enquo(variable)
    df2 <- select(df, starts_with(!!var))
    return(df2)
}
```

How can I run this function with this command:

```
sel(data, instrument)
```

Without needing to quote the parameter "instrument". I need it unquoted as this is part of a bigger function. If I runt it like above I get:

```
Error in is_string(match) : object 'instrument' not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `deparse(substitute(x))` magic! It will return the argument name you pass in as a string.

```r
data <- data.frame(
  name = c("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo", "Stuart", "Pete"),
  instrument1 = c("guitar", "bass", "guitar", "drums", "bass","drums"),
  instrument2 = c("guitar", "bass", "guitar", "drums", "bass","drums"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

sel <- function(df, variable) {
  var <- deparse(substitute(variable))
  df2 <- select(df, starts_with(!!var))
  return(df2)
}

sel(data, instrument)
```

Which returns:

```
  instrument1 instrument2
1      guitar      guitar
2        bass        bass
3      guitar      guitar
4       drums       drums
5        bass        bass
6       drums       drums
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rlang::enexpr` to convert `variable` to name class and then change it to character using `as.character` which is passed as an argument to `starts_with`.

```
sel <- function(df, variable) {
  var <- as.character(rlang::enexpr(variable))
  df2 <- dplyr::select(df, starts_with(var))
  return(df2)
}

sel(data, instrument)

#  instrument1 instrument2
#1      guitar      guitar
#2        bass        bass
#3      guitar      guitar
#4       drums       drums
#5        bass        bass
#6       drums       drums
```